# CD was not burned correctly but content is OK

Tags: linux, iso

I am making a backup of some data. I made an ISO image of the data using `genisoimage` version 1.1.11 using the command:

```
$ genisoimage -l -J -r -o ../image.iso .
```

and then burned it to a CD with

```
$ sudo wodim dev=/dev/sr0 image.iso
```

I then wanted to verify the CD so I first looked at its size with

```
$ sudo isosize -x /dev/sr0
```

which gave me the size of the written track, and then copied the track to
another file with `dd` using the output of `isosize` as block size and count.

Now, the resulting image I got from the CD is smaller than the original image I wrote. So I thought that the CD might be damaged or that the image is too big: the original image is 696 MiB and the CDs have 700 MB declared capacity.

Out of curiosity I mounted both the original image and the one I got from the CD using `mount -o loop`. I then compared the content of both images with

```
$ diff -ru <mount point 1> <mount point 2>
```

and apparently they are exactly the same.

How can it be that the original image has not been written correctly and yet the content of the image is the same?

Does `wodim` perform any translation while burning an image to the medium? This might explain why the tracks on CD are not the same as the original ISO image but the data in the image and in the track is the same.

Or does an ISO image contain some padding at the end so that the image can be use correctly even if the padding is removed?

Comment: Wodim and genisoimage are defective programs that are completely unmaintained since May 2007. Why don't you use the well maintained original software instead of the defective fork?

Comment: @Schily: Thanks for the hint. For some reason I started using `wodim` and `genisoimage` because they are newer and I understood they were the recommended option. I have no problem to go back to `mkisofs` and `cdrecord`.

Comment: `wodim` and `genisoimage` are not newer, they are rather older since they are based on a source state from May 2004 and did not add own useful code. Because of many well known bugs in these versions, they are not recommended either. If your linux distro includes them as the only option, you should ask your distro why they don't deliver up to date software. There are friendly distros like e.g. SUSE, Gentoo or Arch Linux that come with the original cdrtools. Check http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man8/mkisofs.8.html and http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/cdrecord.1.html

Comment: On the computer where I was trying to backup my data I have a Debian derivative (Devuan), which does not provide cdrtools. I have now built cdrtools from source and I am testing it. Alternatvely, I have another computer with a CD burner which has an Arch derivative on it. I might try it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Genisoimage is unmaintained and full of bugs. Never use it for backups!**

This is a fork from the original `mkisofs` program that started in May 2004 and ended in May 2007. It preserves the development state from 2004 and added approx. 50 Debian specific bugs. The original `mkisofs` meanwhile doubled it's size and it's features.

`mkisofs` origins in 1993 and never got an in depth program verification before Summer 2006. In August 2006, many bugs have been identified and fixed, but these fixes never made it into the fork. If you are using an original `mkisofs` from late 2006 or newer, you can be sure that a backup done with `mkisofs` correctly results in a filesystem that is identical to the original.

`isosize` is not a program from the `cdrtools` suite. I cannot tell whether it's output is reliable.

`wodim` is part of the fork and if you use a command line like the one you mentioned, you force it to use an inferior driver. Use the original `cdrecord` program and either omit the `dev=` option completely or use the documented SCSI address syntax. This way, `cdrecord` is able to select the best driver for the device.

BTW: The size of the ISO image created by `mkisofs` is rounded up by padding and a program that only checks the number of sectors mentioned in the ISO-9660 primary volume descriptor may get a value that is too small.

Comment: "If you are using an original mkisofs from late 2006 or newer, you can be sure that a backup done with mkisofs correctly results in a filesystem that is identical to the original.": But this is not my problem. The filesystem in the image contains exactly the same files as the original filesystem on disk. My problem is that the written track is not the same as the ISO image I made. On the other hand, the track on CD and the ISO image from which it was burned contain the same files (and both are equal to the original files I wanted to back up). I find this very strange.

Comment: "BTW: The size of the ISO image created by mkisofs is rounded up by padding and a program that only checks the number of sectors mentioned in the ISO-9660 primary volume descriptor may get a value that is too small.": Maybe this is the problem: I will try re-reading the tracks from the backup CDs using the size of the original ISO image.

Comment: Wodim is so extremely old that I don't remember what write mode it uses by default. It may be Track at Once and then the apparent size is larger than the written size.

Comment: I have checked a blank CD of the same type with `cdrecord -minfo -v` and it has enough space for the entire ISO-image. So maybe the problem is caused by `wodim`: It seems wodim has left out the last sector (2048 bytes). I will now try burning the same image with `cdrecord`.

Comment: Here is the result of my test. `cdrecord` has burned the image correctly: I read the track from the CD and compared it with the original and they are the same. It seems that `wodim` has consistently left out the last sector (I have burned 4 CDs). The data in the CD is OK. I guess the lost sector was part of the padding.

Comment: cdredord by default  writes in session at once mode and this results in media that returns the same number of sectors as have been written and all written sectors are readable. I just checked, the default changed in november 2006. So it may be a write error in wodim or the fact that it writes TAO.